# Symmetry transformation of canonical coordinates of the EM field

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, symmetry, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism

The EM free field can be written with the Hamiltonian formalism as:
$$H=\sum_\lambda\frac 1 2(P_\lambda^2+\omega^2 Q_\lambda^2)$$
In this expression $Q_\lambda$ and $P_\lambda$ are canonical variables.

I've seen that a transformation of the system that transform the variables $Q_\lambda'=Q_\lambda+\delta Q_\lambda$, $P_\lambda'=P_\lambda$ is a symmetry.
My question are, since $Q_\lambda$ is not a geometrical coordinate that I can interpret how do I know that it exist a transformation of the system such that the coordinate $Q_\lambda$change in this why? and if it exist how do I know that it is a symmetry?

Comment: A small typo: $\omega$ will be $\omega^2$. Please cite the source and show how is the given transformation a symmetry.

Comment: the commutation rule for $\hat Q_\lambda$ and $\hat P_\lambda$ derive from symmetry consideration for example